# External Object Query in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, externalid, externalobjects

I have an external object lookup in case. I have a scenario when a record inserted or updated on the case. If the type and subtype field condition matches, I have to check the external object field values and accordingly I have to update the case Status.

Am trying to write external object query in the trigger but its throwing error

> Cannot not reference the external objects in the trigger.

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi AJ, any time you get an error, please include its message text *verbatim*.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian Larson!
Do we have any other possibilities am asking?

Answer (score 3):

You can create triggers on external change data capture events from **OData 4.0** connections

[Apex Considerations for Salesforce Connect External Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_external_objects_considerations.htm)

[Use External Change Data Capture to Track Data Changes on External Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_object_change_tracking_intro.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank, Oleh Berehovskyi!
My requirement Is I want to Query External Data on Case trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Even though documentation is not very clear about how the external objects work it seems that in a sync transaction you cannot access external objects. Try to run a method with @future notation to update your case based on the data of the external object.