# Not being able to query External Object from Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, externalid, lightning-connect, externalobjects

I need to query an external Object from Contact Trigger. If records are present in the external object, then we have to update the contact. Otherwise we have to create the contact.

Now, my issue is that if I try to query the external object records, it gives me the following error

Apex trigger AccountTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: AccountTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.UnexpectedException: Apex triggers can't reference external objects or call out to external data sources.

I went through the below question, but it does not have a solution.

[External Object Query in trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269426/external-object-query-in-trigger)

Comment: Have you tried moving the logic t o asynchronous context? What do you need the data *for*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, querying an External Object means you need a callout. Callouts are not allowed in a DML operation. You need to either query *before* making your first DML operation, or you need to use asynchronous code (future, batchable, queueable, schedulable) to query the object. What you're trying to do is not directly possible.

Comment: I think you put a wrong word in your last sentence "doing to do".

Comment: @AdrianLarson Haha, yeah, it's been a long day.

Comment: @sfdcfox, as I need to do the query from a trigger, there is no way to perform it before the dml operation. Thanks for your help. I will try the alternatives that you suggested.